# How to display certain Wagtail page on the homepage?

Tags: wagtail

I'm making a website where there should be a links to specific pages on the homepage. I'm using PageChooserPanel to do this, but cannot display certain page.
This is my code:

**models.py**

```
class HomePage(Page):

FeaturedPageTitle = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
    )
FeaturedPage = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('FeaturedPageTitle'),
                PageChooserPanel('FeaturedPage'),
            ]),
        ], 
    ]
    def pages(self):
        pages = StandardPage.objects.all()
        return pages

class StandardPage(Page)
```

**home_page.html**

```
{% if page.featured_page %}
{{ page.featured_page_title }}
{% for page in page.pages %}
{% image page.image %}
{{page.title}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called your featured page fields `FeaturedPageTitle` / `FeaturedPage`, but used `featured_page_title` / `featured_page` on the template.

In Python, capitalisation / punctuation in variable names is significant - the normal convention is to use capitals (`CamelCase`) only for class names, and `underscore_case` for other variables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually this code is working and  lists all the pages that I have, but I want to display only one page.

Comment: It's listing all of your pages because that's what `{% for page in page.pages %}` ... `{% endfor %}` does. If you don't want that, then remove that bit from your template.